Create/set "subId" by createSubscription() and get "subId" vrfCoordinatorV2_5Mock calling by javascript in hardhat environment
deploy.js:
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT_LOCALNETWORK = ethers.parseEther("100")

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

  const chainId = network.config.chainId
  let vrfCoordinatorV2_5Address, subscriptionId

  if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {

    const signer = await ethers.getSigner(deployer)
    const vrfCoordinatorV2_5Mock = await deployments.get("VRFCoordinatorV2_5Mock")
    vrfCoordinatorV2_5Address = vrfCoordinatorV2_5Mock.address
    const transactionResponse = await ethers.getContractAt("VRFCoordinatorV2_5Mock", vrfCoordinatorV2_5Address, signer)

    const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.waitForDeployment(1)
    const createSubIdSend = await transactionResponse.createSubscription()
    const createSubIdReceipt = await createSubIdSend.wait(1)
    subscriptionId = createSubIdReceipt.events[0].args.subId

    console.log("+++++++")
    console.log(createSubIdReceipt)
    console.log("+++++++")

    await vrfCoordinatorV2_5Address.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT_LOCALNETWORK)

  } else {
    vrfCoordinatorV2_5Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
    subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
  }

  const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"]
  const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["keyHash"]
  const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"]
  const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]

  const args = [vrfCoordinatorV2_5Address, entranceFee, gasLane, subscriptionId, callbackGasLimit, interval]

  const blub = await deploy("Blub", {
    from: deployer,
    args: args,
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
  })

  if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && vars.has("ETHERSCAN_API_KEY")) {
    log("Verifying...")
    await verify(blub.address, args)
  }
  log("--------------------------")
}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "blub"]



Deploying on Remix EVM VRFCoordinatorV2_5Mock.sol (Docs: Local testing using a mock subscription contract, Open VRFCoordinatorV2_5Mock.sol in Remix) and execute createSubscription() by clicking the response contains something like this:

[
    {
        "from": "0xf8e81D47203A594245E36C48e151709F0C19fBe8",
        "topic": "0x1d3015d7ba850fa198dc7b1a3f5d42779313a681035f77c8c03764c61005518d",
        "event": "SubscriptionCreated",
        "args": {
            "0": "47981876831974981583908267211354528802403014529003720113040138979071725636107",
            "1": "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4",
            "subId": "47981876831974981583908267211354528802403014529003720113040138979071725636107",
            "owner": "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4"
        }
    }
]


I expect a response similar to this above like in Remix EVM by calling the following line on the hardhat environment:

  const createSubIdSend = await transactionResponse.createSubscription()


Response console.log(createSubIdReceipt):

ContractTransactionReceipt {
  provider: HardhatEthersProvider {
    _hardhatProvider: LazyInitializationProviderAdapter {
      _providerFactory: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
      _emitter: [EventEmitter],
      _initializingPromise: [Promise],
      provider: [BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter]
    },
    _networkName: 'hardhat',
    _blockListeners: [],
    _transactionHashListeners: Map(0) {},
    _eventListeners: []
  },
  to: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  contractAddress: null,
  hash: '0xf98cf0ad6d06ea315b959d7d5ebbf50b0c9cc8105b0405ef9e83af89a1326a27',
  index: 0,
  blockHash: '0x081acdc1233ef2c9395d4470d6a214f8a18b655a12d4c363c990a307d7bea295',
  blockNumber: 2,
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000400000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  gasUsed: 146429n,
  blobGasUsed: undefined,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 146429n,
  gasPrice: 1018497265n,
  blobGasPrice: undefined,
  type: 2,
  status: 1,
  root: undefined
}

I want to get "subId", but I get an:
Error: ERROR processing .../deploy.js:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

while trying to get "subId" with subscriptionId = createSubIdReceipt.events[0].args.subId
I see there is no "subId" in createSubIdReceipt... What am I doing wrong?

Instead of events, it should be the logs array, inside the createSubIdReceipt object.
So, replace this line:
subscriptionId = createSubIdReceipt.events[0].args.subId

with:
subscriptionId = createSubIdReceipt.logs[0].args.subId


Thank you :) I thought I already tried it in this way, but I think without using brackets...
